# How to create an XML sitemap in Magento for multiple stores?

Tags: xml-sitemap, multilingual, internationalization, magento

I have created these sitemaps because there are multiple stores.  There is only one admin account for all the stores and it does not allow my to create multiple files names "sitemap.xml".

- `www.example.co.uk/sitemap.xml`
- `www.example.fr/french.xml`
- `www.example.ie/ireland.xml`

Will this work?

Comment: Will what work?   Not naming each sitemap "sitemap.xml"?

Comment: No I can't do backend allowed us to created only one sitemap.xml